# How to save mysql elements in different variables on join

Tags: php, mysql, join, datatables, union

I got 2 tables called "Users",and "message":

```
"Users":                       
id | username                 
----------                   
38 | test            
39 | test1          
40 | test2           

"message"
 messageid | source | target |subject      | date
 ------------------------------------------------
 100       | 38     | 39     | Hello       | September
 100       | 39     | 38     | RE: Hello   | November 
 300       | 38     | 40     | Your car    | October
```

I would like to show in an html table the most recent message from each "messageid"-group together with the username. But the username should never be myself (i.e. never the user who is currently logged in).

**For example:** User 39 (=test1) is logged in and wrote the last recent message within the "message-id"-group 100 in November with subject "RE:Hello". In my table I would like to show only that last subject "RE:Hello" in the next column of that table "test" (=id 38).

**That's my query for mysql so far:**

```
    $result=("SELECT message.id message.source, message.target, message.subject, 
message.date, Users.username, max(message.date) FROM message JOIN Users  
ON message.source = Users.id
WHERE (message.target = ? OR message.source = ?) GROUP BY
message.messageid ORDER BY message.date DESC", $_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['id']);
```

This query gives me the most current message out of every messageid-group.

**But what I basically want** and really stuck with is not only the Users.username for message.source = Users.id but also the Users.username for message.target = Users.id. Because I could then go in php through a foreach loop where I would have an if/else statement:

```
if (message.source == $_SESSION['id']){echo Users.username of        
   message.target)};

else {echo Users.username of message.source};
```

I am only a beginner in programming and I hope this explanation is not too confusing. I definitely would appreciate any help / ideas.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you trying to create tree structured comments system? it seems like you have bad database structure

Comment: I am trying to create a message system, where I click on a message (the most current message within the messageid-group) and it shows me then the whole conversation (i.e. all the older messages). But for that most current message, I would like to show the user I have the conversation with, no matter, if the last message came from myself